# How to figure out who has deleted a question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

To the best of my understanding, there are three roles on Stack Exchange family websites who are able to delete a question:

1. Moderators
2. Voting users with reputation > 10000
3. Question owners

Are there ways for non-owner users to find which question is deleted by which role(s)?

Comment: Yes, in the timeline. (Click the clock button at the left under the voting buttons)  but if you have < 10K reputation you need to be the owner of the post to see that (as only with 10K you can see deleted posts)

Comment: @Glorfindel Does that duplicate really answers this question? I'm reluctant to cast a re-open vote as that will hammer it open and I rather not end-up with you (or any of the other voters) in a close/re-open  war.

Comment: @rene It doesn't really. The section *What does deletion mean for a post?* semi-addresses this question (it talks about the display of deleted posts on their former links), but I think this question asks about there being *any* ways to find out (other than on the former links themselves). As I don't have a hammer, I've cast a normal vote.

Comment: @Glorfindel See my comment above. I don't really think this is a dupe.

Comment: The answer does start at the section with the text: "[Can I still see my own post even after it's deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/282094)" and is vaguely hinted to new users, and somewhat more clearly explained to seasoned vets, in the following few sections - so **the dupe** ***target*** **is correct**. --- That the FAQ should be clearer doesn't affect its status as the correct dupe; even if another is better such should be suggested and edited into the banner's list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't easily do this for currently deleted posts. For any post the delete event is visible in the [Post Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/342045/timeline). It is possible to find posts that were deleted and later undeleted as those are in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1339158) shows for once deleted posts if they were deleted by their owner. There isn't an easy to use (historical) list of moderators in SEDE so I didn't bother to check if the delete was done by a moderator. I have added one way to get moderators by looking at users who have applied postnotices as that is a mod only feature. That list isn't guaranteed to contain all mods. There might be additional ways to find  mods. That is left as an exercise  for the reader.

```sql
;with mods as (
select distinct owneruserid 
   --  , max(postid) as [Post Link]
from postnotices pn
inner join postnoticetypes pnt on pnt.id = pn.postnoticetypeid
where pnt.classid <> 2 -- Bounty
and owneruserid <> 152859 -- data bugs
)

select distinct 
       postid as [Post Link]
     , text
     , case 
       when p.owneruserid = voters.userid then 'owner' 
       when voters.userid in (select owneruserid from mods) then '(former) mod'
       else null 
       end [role]
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
cross apply openjson(text, '$.Voters')  with (userid int '$.Id') voters
where posthistorytypeid = 13
```

Do know there is also a possibility to delete a post via review. When a post gets flagged as Very Low Quality or Not an answer in enters a review queue where reviewers can delete a post, if enough of them agree. Those reviewers don't need to have > 10K reputation or a diamond to make that delete happen.

More information on how deleting works is found in [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)